# Who is Madhavi, performer of Sharanagati?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, sharanagati, thenkalai

The Sri Vachana Bhushanam is a work by the 13th century Sri Vaishnava Acharya Pillai Lokacharya on the subject of Sharanagati, complete surrender to Sriman Narayana as a means to attain Moksha and other fruits.  In verse 32 of the Sri Vachana Bhushanam, Pillai Lokacharya lists various scriptural examples of people who have performed Sharanagati:

> The fact that there is no restriction of qualification [for Sharanagati] has these examples: the Pandavas beginning with Yudhishthira, Draupadi, Kakasura, Kaliya, Gajendra Alvan, Perumal [Rama], Ilaya Perumal [Lakshmana], **and others**; as they have all done Sharanagati, there is no restriction of qualification.

In his commentary on this verse, the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Manavala Mamunigal elaborates on the “and others” part by listing several more scriptural examples of Sharanagati:

> "toṭakkamāṉavarkaḷ” eṉkaiyālē “sōham tvām caraṇampāra mapramēyam samprāpta: paramapatam yatō na kiñcit samsāra cramaparitāpa tapta cētā nirvāṇa pariṇatatāmni sāpilāṣ” eṉṟu mucukuntaṉum, “mūṭōya malpamati ralpa vicēṣṭitōyam kliṣṭam manōsya viṣayair namayiprasaṅki, ittam krupāṅ kuru mayi praṇatēkilēca tavām stōtu mampuja pavōpihi tēva nēca:” eṉṟu caṣatrapantuvum, **“pakavantam prapannāsā pakavantamavāp ha” eṉṟu mātaviyum**, “tam prapinnacirōkrīvam āsyēpya: sruta cōṇitam vilōkya caraṇam jakmus tatpatn'yō matusūtanam” eṉṟu kāḷiyapattikaḷum, “praṇāma pravaṇā nāta taitya sain'ya parājitā: caraṇam tvā manuprāptās samastā tēvatā tēvatā kaṇā:” eṉṟu intrāti tēvarkaḷum, “rāṣasair vatyamānānām vānarāṇām mahācamū: caraṇyam caraṇam yātā rāmam tacaratātmajam” eṉṟu srīvānara sēṉaiyum
>
> “And others” refers to Muchukunda described by [a Bhagavatam verse], Kshatrabandhu described by [a Vishnudharma Purana verse], **Madhavi described by “she who did Sharanagati to Bhagavan reached him”**, the wives of Kaliya described by [a Vishnu Purana verse], the Devas beginning with Indra described by “oh Lord, the Devas defeated by the armies of the Daityas stood interested in worshiping you and surrounded to you”, and the holy army of the Vanaras described by [a Valmiki Ramayana verse].

I’m interested in the part in bold.  My question is, who is this woman Madhavi who did Sharanagati and then attained Moksha?

And what scripture is the verse describing her from?  Here is the verse:

> bhagavantam prapannā sā bhāgavantamavāpaha

Do any subcommentaries on Manavala Mamunigal’s commentary shed light on this?

Comment: Did Meera done sharanagati? I found that Madhavi was another name of Meera.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Meera lived long after the time of Manavala Mamunigal, who is speaking about some scriptural verse here.  So it would be some ancient woman named Madhavi described in Hindu scripture.  And no, as far as I know Meera never did Sharanagati.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan There is a gopi named Madhavi, close associate of Radha. I am doubting whether she may the girl.